# What to enter into "Client" field in the Perforce setup dialog in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5?

Tags: intellij-idea, perforce

I'm trying to set up Perforce integration in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2. There is a field named "Client" that doesn't make sense to me. I get the message "Connection problems: Client Unknown" whatever I type into the field. What should I enter into that field?

Answer (score 20):

You need to enter the name of your Perforce workspace.

If you have set up the command line tool correctly you may run `p4 set P4CLIENT` on the command-line.

If you use the P4V GUI tool, the workspace name is easily found.

Comment: If it's not set, then `p4 set P4ClIENT` won't return anything. Since I mostly use p4v mine isn't set. Also, if you haven't created a client\workspace(those names are interchangeable) you'll have to do that before you can use it in IntelliJ.

Comment: You can just run `p4 set` to see the values of all the P4 variables.

Comment: @ArneEvertsson: `p4 set` will return nothing when you haven't set *any* environment variables.

Comment: `p4 set` returns `P4CLIENT=Legacy (config)` for me, and the Workspace name in p4v shows as "Legacy," but the IntelliJ Test Connection window shows:

`P4CLIENT=Legacy (config)`
`Client unknown Client unknown Client unknown Client unknown`

Any guesses on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Open P4V and connect. On the top left, above everything, there are your:

> [client], [port], [user] - Perforce P4V

They often look something like:

> [client] ~ [your-name]_[random-letters-and-numbers]
>
> [port] ~ [url]:[number]
>
> [user] ~ [your-name]

Enter them in IntelliJ and press Apply.

---

**Edit:**

If you only see

> [port], [user] - Perforce P4V

you need to go to **Connection -> New workspace...** and create a workspace.

Comment: doesn't work. It tires to connect to 127.0.0.1:port: connect to server failed. Where does it get the 127.0.0.1 from?

Comment: @Nickpick, did you include the server in the port field?  The field expects [server]:[port].

Answer (score 2):

You need to enter the local Workspace name into the dialog in Webstorm Options / Preferences to integrate it with Perforce.

In P4V, you can find this by looking at View > Workspace Tree, and then selecting the workspace you are trying to integrate.

Background: I'm setting up Perforce with Webstorm v2016.1 just now. I tried using the name of the workspace stream on the server at first, which kept giving me a "Client Unknown" error. This fixed the issue and allowed the connection to go through.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/intro/index.html before you go any further. Always start by reading the docs, you'll be a lot happier.

Comment: You're kind of right. But sometimes you just want to get started, check out code and build. It's isnt't exactly clear why one thing has two different names (Client and Workspace). BTW, the whole IntelliJ Perforce setup dialog is a mess.