# Perforce - Client Unknown error (in webstorm)

Tags: perforce, webstorm

I am getting a "client unknown" error when trying to commit any files from webstorm to perforce. My p4v is configured correctly and works outside of Webstorm and my p4 command line is also correctly configured yet when I use the exact same setup in webstorm I get the client unknown error. My client is setup and correctly copied into perforce. Any idea what might be going on here? Are there logs that will show me a more complete error?

Comment: Such error normally indicates that Perforce connection configuration is not properly set up. What do your settings in Settings/Version control/Perforce look like? Can you attach a screenshot + idea.log? What does 'test connection' report?

Comment: Client is synonymous with "workspace" in p4v...make sure your workspace is setup and named correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to enter into "Client" field in the Perforce setup dialog in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399936/what-to-enter-into-client-field-in-the-perforce-setup-dialog-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out finally, though I ran into a new issue.

**Resolution:** The perforce client P4 (not P4v) has to be installed, and it was but it was not in the correct directory. P4 needs to be installed in your Applications on a Mac and that file needs to be made editable. You will also likely need to change your permissions for that file to allow system read/write access.

To make the file executable once it is in the Applications directory from the command prompt navigate to your applications directory and type: chmod +x p4 (http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/01_install.html)

Then you can find the file in finder and right click it, the click get info from the context menu. From there at the very bottom will be file permissions. I set them all to read/write. You could also do this from the command line by typing chmod 755 p4 I think but I am not great on the command line so use at your own risk.

As far as your workspace is concerned that should be whatever your workspace is set to in P4V.

At that point if you hit test connection inside Webstorm->preferences->perforce it should work or at least give you a new error with some more information.

Mine was able to connect successfully but now when I try to update a file I get an error saying "path '/users/my-path.....' is not under the client's root '/users/my-path' even though the first path specified is clearly a child of the second path. Still working on this error.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are facing this issue :

Check the "`p4 info`" output and see if "User name", "Client name" and Client are having correct data.

If they are 'none' / 'unknown', then check or set below environment variables

1. P4CLIENT
2. P4USER
3. P4PORT

**P4CLIENT** : Should match with your "workspace" name

**P4USER** : Username to login to perforce

**P4PORT** : Should have proper URL "HOSTNAME:PORT" of perforce server : Ex: 192.128.10.130:6666

Comment: You save my time , Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Mine was able to connect successfully but now when I try to update a file I get an error saying "path '/users/my-path.....' is not under the client's root '/users/my-path' even though the first path specified is clearly a child of the second path. Still working on this error.

In my case i resolve this problem -> i had physical way to my files **/Users/....** but in perforce i had a root like **/users/....** (in lowercase), i change root and its help for me in mac